# Syntax Error Creating Trigger - Column Specification

Tags: postgresql

What is wrong with the trigger definition below?  I intend it to execute the "calculate_dow" function whenever the "date" column is updated or inserted but it generates the following error ...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_calculate_dow
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OF date ON focusblu.events
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_dow(date);
```

> Failed to execute SQL : SQL CREATE TRIGGER tr_calculate_dow AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OF date ON focusblu.events FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_dow(date); failed : ERROR: syntax error at or near "OF" LINE 1: ...IGGER tr_calculate_dow AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OF date ON... ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you have a syntax error: You cannot use `OF` there.

The documentation is pretty clear on exactly what you want to, and even has examples based on your "whenever date column is update" criteria:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Perhaps you wanted something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_calculate_dow
  AFTER UPDATE ON focusblu.events
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.date IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.date)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_dow(NEW.date);
```

You'll most likely want to do the same for another INSERT trigger as well and just pick the date.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your will update the date on each update so you don't have to specify the `date`field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_calculate_dow
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON focusblu.events
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_dow(date);
```

Comment: Not exactly.  I want to update another column using the "calculate_dow" function whenever the "date" column is inserted or updated.

Comment: However, removing the 'OF date' condition did eliminate the error and the trigger now works.  I guess this is OK for my purposes but I'm not sure why I can't define the trigger to execute only when 'date' is updated or inserted.